# Web Service querying database with LINQ fails on one computer, not the other

Tags: c#, linq, webforms

I've developed a small Web Forms application locally on my computer, and it works well, but when I moved it to a different computer, a web service that I'm querying with AJAX fails.

Here's the relevant code:

```
/*Search for Event.country by name*/
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string[] GetVenues(string searchterm)
    {
        var _db = new MyApp.Models.EventContext();

        var myResult = from e in _db.Events
                       where e.venue.Contains(searchterm)
                       select e.venue;

        return myResult.Distinct().ToArray();
    }
```

I suspect my problem is with the OnModelCreating method in the EventContext class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Event>().ToTable("events");
    }
```

I backed up the database from my local computer and restored it on the other, so I suspect I'm doing something wrong with OnModelCreating since the table already exists. Are my assumptions correct?

Here's the error message I get as a response from the Web Serivce as viewed by Firebug:

```
{"Message":"An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.","StackTrace":" 
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) 
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase> b__4(InternalContext c)
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction'1.PerformAction(TInput input) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action'1 action)
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet'1.Initialize()
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet'1.get_InternalContext()
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery'1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
 at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable'1 source, Expression'1 predicate)
at MyApp.WebServices.AutoComplete.GetVenues(String searchterm)","ExceptionType":"System.Data.DataException"}
```

Comment: The message says you should inspect the inner exception for more details. How about doing that?

Comment: I thought I wrote it in my question, but I must have lost it when I restructured it: the code is running at my friend's computer, and I don't have access to debugging it there.

Comment: Adding a logger and getting the log file from your friend would help too.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to clarify what exactly is the source of the problem from the data provided.

Your comments state that you don't have access to debug the application on your friend's computer. Have you tried [Remote Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx) within Visual Studio?

You may also want to check if you have nullable types defined within your database, or column values that may not be the same as database defaults. This would indicate an issue with the data, and the reason for the [DataException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataexception.aspx)